# Telnet / Security Groups

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, telnet, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I'm in the middle of installing and configuring an XMPP server, using ejabberd on Windows server 2012, running on an EC2 box.

I have opened port 5222 within windows firewall, and added to the security group for the EC2 instance

```
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
5222
0.0.0.0/0
ejabberd_c2s

Custom TCP Rule
TCP
5222
::/0
ejabberd_c2s
```

My XMPP logins are not working, and so I've turned to telnet to try and debug - it sees that port 5222 is reporting as closed:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> telnet hostname.com 5222
Connecting To hostname.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5222: Connect failed
```

Any guidance or steps towards debugging would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was in ejabberd's default configuration of "::" as an IP to listen, which forced it to listen only to IPv6.

By updating the ejabbed config to

```
port: 5222
ip: "0.0.0.0"
module: ejabberd_c2s
```

I was able to connect via telnet, and able to access the server using XMPP.